# Formik onSubmit function is not working on my code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I am creating a form by using react and formik.Below is my code:

```
<div>
  <Formik
    initialValues={{
      email: ""
    }}
    onSubmit={(values: FState, setSubmitting: any) => {
      console.log("Enter in submit function", values);
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        setSubmitting(false);
      }, 500);
    }}
    validationSchema={validationSchemaGlobal}
  >
    {({
      errors,
      touched,
      handleBlur,
      handleChange,
      isSubmitting,
      values,
      handleSubmit
    }: any) => (
      <div>
        <Cards>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <CardBody>
              <h4>
                Enter Your Email Address and we'll send you a link to reset your
                password
              </h4>
              <Field
                type="text"
                id="email"
                value={values.email}
                component={CustomInput}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
              />
              {errors.email && touched.email ? (
                <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.email}</div>
              ) : null}
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter>
              <br />
              <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                Send Password Reset Link
                {/* {isSubmitting && <i className="fa fa-sponner fa-spin"/>} */}
              </button>
            </CardFooter>
          </form>
        </Cards>
      </div>
    )}
  </Formik>
</div>
```

In this formik form, onSubmit function not working. I dont know why? Please tell me guys what is problem with my code?

Comment: Do you mean that it is broken, or is the `onSubmit` method not called at all? I think you should call the second argument of the `onSubmit` method `actions` instead, and use `actions.setSubmitting` instead of just `setSubmitting` since it is an object that gets passed to it, and not a function.

Comment: @Tholle onSubmit not working.I have already done actions.setSubmitting but didn't work.

Comment: I tried to run your code, and with the bits you didn't provide stripped out it does work:
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-3kdov?fontsize=14 So I removed: `component={CustomInput}` and changed all the other custom components to be div, and changed the validation schema as you didn't provide yours. Maybe the issue is in your CustomInput or the validation?

Comment: remove the validation schema and check, I mean validationSchema: null.

Comment: I faced a similar issue and removing the validation schema helped me to solve it.
I think I need to check if I have any fields that is not being evaluated.

Comment: replace <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> with <Form> from formik

Answer (score 253):

Check your `validationSchema`. I ran into this problem and found that my validator was returning something that signaled to Formik the form was invalid, but no other warnings or messages were coming up. It just wouldn't submit.

Replace that prop with `validator={() => ({})}` i.e. just an empty object being returned. That should pass validation and trigger your onSubmit. You can restore your functionality from there.

```
  <Formik
    initialValues={{
      email: ""
    }}
    onSubmit={() => { console.log("submit!"); }}
    validator={() => ({})}
  >
    {/* */}
  </Formik>
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed my problem! I'm using Yup and had an additional field validation setup as required which wasn't linked to any field, so it never passed validation.

Comment: @AlexP Hey, I am facing similar issue.May I know how you fix your problem.

Comment: There should be some type of notification for this. Not at all obvious

Comment: one error wouldn't hurt there. Thanks, Chris for identifying this

Comment: @NickKinlen suggestion solve it for me as well.    To figured it outI added this to display the errors:  `{!isValid && JSON.stringify(errors)}`

Answer (score 52):

In my case I use [`Yup`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) as validator and I accidentally had `firstName` and `lastName` in my `validationSchema` as required but I did not have those values in my form.

My `validationSchema` was,

```
const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  firstName: Yup.string()
    .min(2, 'Too Short!')
    .max(50, 'Too Long!')
    .required('Required'),
  lastName: Yup.string()
    .min(2, 'Too Short!')
    .max(50, 'Too Long!')
    .required('Required'),
  email: Yup.string()
    .email('Invalid email')
    .required('Required'),
  password: Yup.string()
    .min(6, 'Password must be at least 6 characters')
    .max(24, 'Password can be maximum 24 characters')
    .required('Required')
})
```

I just deleted `firstName` and `lastName`,

```
const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string()
    .email('Invalid email')
    .required('Required'),
  password: Yup.string()
    .min(6, 'Password must be at least 6 characters')
    .max(24, 'Password can be maximum 24 characters')
    .required('Required')
})
```

So check your `validationSchema` and see if you require something that does not exist in your form.

Comment: You just saved me such a headache. Thank you

Comment: man this worked but thinking about it, i hope , it should have just ignored that validation

Comment: I wasted a couple of hours figuring this out. Then came across this. Thanks

Comment: This was my problem too, my validation schema had a typo in the property, so I couldn't see the validation fails either.

Comment: In my case I changed the input name and initial values from "email" to "username" but forgot to update validationSchema. Now everything works just fine.

Answer (score 13):

I imported `Form` from `react-bootstrap` instead of `formik`, so I was having this issue. The issue was solved by importing the `Form` of `formik`. Sometimes, directly using `Form.Control` of react-bootstrap instead of `Field` of formik also gives this issue.

If you really have to use `Form.Control` you can use `render` prop.

Comment: does not worked for me :(

Comment: this works only if you have used Form of bootstrap instead of Formik

Comment: can you share the syntax of rendor prop

Answer (score 6):

A little bit late for the original question but I experienced the same issue and solved it easy but hard to find.

When I passed the "name" prop to the component I had written "DateOfBirth" instead of with lowercase, which means it didn't match my validationSchema.

My schema looks like this:

```
export const userSchema = yup.object().shape({
firstName: yup.string().min(1).max(50).required('Field is required'), 
lastName: yup.string().min(1).max(50).required('Field is required'), 
dateOfBirth: yup.date().required('Invalid input'),});
```

This menas the name of the component has to match

Before (Didn't work):

```
 <DateTimePicker name="DateOfBirth" label="Date of birth" />
```

After (Worked):

```
<DateTimePicker name="dateOfBirth" label="Date of birth" />
```

Comment: Thanks, pal! That's was my problem as well!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, **onSubmit** was not working because I forgot to wrap my form in the `<form></form>` tag. A stupid issue, but it can be the reason for this behavior. If the above solutions don't work, check that you have the **form** tag.

Comment: same issue here, forgetful much!

Comment: Would one not expect <Formik> to wrap your code in a form??? Geeesh. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4):

In my case, mistakenly I have passed `validationSchema` to wrong prop.

Error:

```js
  <Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    validate={validationSchema} <----- Error
  >
```

Proper way:

```js
  <Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    validationSchema={validationSchema} <----- Good
  >
```

Answer (score 2):

This may happen because the form is being submitted but it is invalid , this may happen because the validation schema is not matching ur form for more than one reason ,

**in my case** , it was because there was a string , and it is been sent as null , so I just added `.nullable()` to the validation schema for that field.

Answer (score 2):

I am mentioning one more possibility through which i handled.
change the button type and add onClick like this

```
<Button type="button" onClick={submitForm}>
```

also add submitForm prop at top along with values, touched etc

```
 {({ submitForm, errors, handleChange, handleSubmit, touched, values }) => (
```

now its working

Answer (score 2):

Had extra field in my validationSchema which was declared with Yup. however that field wasn't declared in Formik hence it didn't work. After removing the field from validationSchema, it works.

Answer (score 2):

To the people who is facing error:

**make sure initialValue Objkeys matches the Yup validation schema**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That was helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. My onSubmit function was not executing onClick on submit button.

The problem was in Yup.validation schema. There was an extra field that I did not use. I remove that field and boom.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as I had the same pronlem and the problem was even different:

My validation function was returning an `errors` object that always contained all fields, all with empty strings when they were correct.

Form submission seems disabled when the `errors` object is not empty.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33730870)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was Button component was outside the Formik component

```
<Formik initialValues={} validate={validate} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <Form>      
   </Form>
</Formik>
<Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
```

Moving the Button inside Form solved my issue

```
<Formik initialValues={} validate={validate} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <Form>      
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
   </Form>
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was I was not initializing error with blank on validation

```
 const errors:any={};
```

Here is full code for login form, check the validate function

```
    <Formik
     initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
     validate={(formValues) => {
         const errors:any={};
         if (!formValues.email) {
             errors.email = "Invalid email";
         }
         if (!formValues.password) {
             errors.password = "Password is required";
         }
         return errors;

     }}
     onSubmit={async (values) => {
         console.log("submit", values);
         dispatch(login({ username: values.email, password: values.password }));
         if (loginState.isError) {
             alert(loginState.message);
         }
     }}
 >{({ values, handleChange, errors, dirty, isValid, isSubmitting, handleSubmit, setFieldValue, setFieldTouched, setFieldError }) => (
     <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <FormGroup>
             <Label>Email</Label>
             <Input type="email" name="email" valid={!isEmpty(errors.email)} value={values.email} onChange={handleChange}></Input>
             <FormFeedback className="font-weight-bold" type="invalid" role="alert"> {errors.email}</FormFeedback>
         </FormGroup>
         <FormGroup>
             <Label>Password</Label>
             <Input type="password" name="password" value={values.password} valid={!isEmpty(errors.password)} onChange={handleChange}></Input>
             <FormFeedback className="font-weight-bold" type="invalid" role="alert"> {errors.password}</FormFeedback>

         </FormGroup>
         <FormGroup className="text-center">
         <p> {isValid === true ? "is valid" : "not valid"} </p>
             <Button type="submit" color="primary" className="mt-3">Login</Button>
         </FormGroup>
     </Form>
 )}
 </Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this because I declared the onsubmit function without the const word (I know it's stupid)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also print out the errors before returning the JSX for the form and that should help you find out what the issue is. That's what worked for me:

```
<div>
  <Formik
    initialValues={{
      email: ""
    }}
    onSubmit={(values: FState, setSubmitting: any) => {
      console.log("Enter in submit function", values);
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        setSubmitting(false);
      }, 500);
    }}
    validationSchema={validationSchemaGlobal}
  >
    {({
      errors,
      touched,
      handleBlur,
      handleChange,
      isSubmitting,
      values,
      handleSubmit
    }: any) => {
      
      // ADD THIS
      console.log(errors)

      return (<div>
        ... your form here
      </div>)
    }}
  </Formik>
</div>
```

Answer (score -5):

Use  instead of button tag as i worked for me.

Comment: This is the best answer on StackOverflow in the history of forever.