# 'handleSubmit' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Line 111:22:  'handleSubmit' is not defined. Where and how do I call the handleSubmit

```
  const MyForm = ( handleSubmit, setvalues, values, handleBlur, handleChange, touched, errors ) => {

  const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    NameoftheUPSIProject: '',
    InformationSharedBy: '',
    InfoSharedwithrespectto: '',
    InsiderTypes: '',
    ContactPerson: '',
    NameoftheOrganization: '',
    DateofSharing: '',
    ParticularofInformationShared: '',
    PurposeofSharing: '',
    ModeofSharing: '',
  },
  validationSchema: formValidation,
  onSubmit: (values) => {
    apple(values);
  },
});
```

}

I have removed earlier errors, but I am now facing this error:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uwfZR36JMvscNMvdSyB9g6AZE3Gj_sdnuU2-c-XcwTM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [handleSubmit is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71068135/handlesubmit-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `props` to take in all props to your component, like so:

```
const MyForm = (props) => {...}
```

And then access each prop using `props.handleSubmit` and so on.
Or you can use destructuring likes this:

```
const MyForm = ({ handleSubmit, setvalues, values, handleBlur, handleChange, touched, errors }) => {...}
```

You were missing curly braces in your code, which could be why you can't read any of the props

Comment: not working bro

Comment: Did you call the handleSubmit in your code? Because in the provided code, handleSubmit isn't called anywhere.

Comment: yes handle submit called error gone

Comment: So it is working now? If it is, and my answer helped you, you can accept my answer. If its still not working take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237482/formik-onsubmit-function-is-not-working-on-my-code
Also this https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1733

Comment: sorry bro i didn't use props